# SQLSTATE and SQLCODE equivalent in Big Query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, google-bigquery, teradata, rdbms

I was going through SQLSTATE and SQLCODE in Teradata's Stored Prcedures documentation. I am trying to migrate a Teradata's stored procedure to cloud. What is equivalent for these in Big query?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the use of `SQLCODE` is no longer advised. Quoting the [Teradata documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/zzfV8dn%7ElAaKSORpulwFMg/PbPb%7EYud_3c%7Ec6AYSU6KDg):

> #### ANSI Compliance
>
> `SQLCODE` is not ANSI/ISO SQL:2011-compliant. `SQLCODE` was deprecated in the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 standard and is not defined in the SQL:2011 standard. The ANSI/ISO SQL committee recommends that new applications be written using SQLSTATE (see [`SQLSTATE` on page 91](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/zzfV8dn%7ElAaKSORpulwFMg/5vBlAaOzxB6CPkLlsQ7gAA)) in place of `SQLCODE`.

For mapping `SQLSTATE` to BigQuery, see [Google's migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migration/dw2bq/td2bq/td-bq-sql-translation-reference-tables#error_conditions):

> #### Error condition handlers
>
> Teradata uses handlers on status codes in procedures for error control. In BigQuery, error handling is a core feature of the main control flow, similar to what other languages provide with `TRY ... CATCH` blocks.
>
> ```
> Teradata                  | BigQuery
> --------------------------+------------------------------------
> DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR  | BEGIN ... EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN 
> SQLEXCEPTION              | 
>                           |
> SIGNAL sqlstate           | RAISE message
>                           |
> DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER  | Exception handlers that trigger for certain 
> FOR SQLSTATE VALUE 23505; | error conditions are not used by BigQuery
> ```
>
> The `SQLSTATE` variable in Teradata is similar to the [`@@error` system variable](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#system_variables) in BigQuery. In BigQuery, it is more common to investigate errors using [audit logging](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs) or the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-routines?hl=en) views.

And [also](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migration/dw2bq/td2bq/td-bq-sql-translation-reference-tables#error_codes_and_messages):

> Teradata error codes and BigQuery error codes are different. Providing a REST API, BigQuery relies primarily on HTTP status codes plus detailed error messages.
>
> If your application logic is currently catching the following errors, try to eliminate the source of the error, because BigQuery will not return the same error codes.
>
> - `SQLSTATE = '02000'`—"Row not found"
> - `SQLSTATE = '21000'`—"Cardinality violation (Unique Index)"
> - `SQLSTATE = '22000'`—"Data violation (Data Type)"
> - `SQLSTATE = '23000'`—"Constraint Violation"

It is clear there is no one-to-one correspondence of `SQLSTATE` with anything in BigQuery, so you'll need to rewrite some of your code based on the above information.