# Teradata - SQLSTATE equivalent in Big Query

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery, teradata, bq

I'm trying to find a equivalent to the below queries in BIGQUERY.
We are working on a Teradata to Big Query conversion. We want to know the equivalent query or how to write in big query.

```
     DECLARE a CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '50000';
     DECLARE b CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '50001';
     
     DECLARE EXIT HANDLER
     FOR a , b 
       INSERT INTO Proc_Error ('50000 & 50001',
          'updateSalesData', 'CONDITION HANDLER');
 
     DECLARE EXIT HANDLER
     FOR NOT FOUND
       INSERT INTO Proc_Error ('NOT FOUND',
        'updateSalesData', 'Generic no data found handler performed');

     DECLARE EXIT HANDLER
     FOR SQLWARNING
       INSERT INTO Proc_Error ('SQLWARNING',
              'updateSalesData', 'Generic exit warning handler performed');
             
      DECLARE EXIT HANDLER
      FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        INSERT INTO Proc_Error ('SQLEXCEPTION',
           'updateSalesData', 'Generic exit handler performed'); 
     
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
      FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        INSERT INTO Proc_Error ('SQLEXCEPTION',
           'updateSalesData', 'Generic continue handler performed');
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894125/sqlstate-and-sqlcode-equivalent-in-big-query ?

Comment: @Fred, It was some how. But, I had this question posted now on how the sample handler statement is return in BigQuery.

Comment: Any idea,  from online writing I could see the above declare handlers is not supported in big query store procedure?? instead we have to call the exception at the run time call using **BEGIN ... EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN END**;